# 18.11.19 20:35:29 : Message is missing sender's address mail() error

Tags: php, html, email

```
    <?php
        $to = "****";
        $message = "Hello, world!";
        $topic = "HELLO, WORLD!";
        mail($to, $topic, $message ); 

    ?>

[mail function]
smtp = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" 

[sendmail]
smtp_server = smtp.google.com
smtp_port = 587

auth_username = ****
auth_password = ****

[error.log: 18.11.19 20:35:29 : Message is missing sender's address]
```

че делать парни хэлп

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ошибке же написано "нет адреса отправителя". Его можно установить через дополнительные заголовки

```
$to = "****";
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = "Hello, world!";
$headers = array(
    'From' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'Reply-To' => 'webmaster@example.com'
);

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Или отправив дополнительные аргементы командной строки в sendmail:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, null, '-fwebmaster@example.com');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php